# React-router 4 always reloading the browser on history.push

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

React-router 4 `this.props.history.push('/url');` always reloading the browser and hence the global redux state is getting cleared on each page transition.

Comment: Hi, I am also getting a same experience. is there any resolution in the updated react router dom ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue after upgrading react. The problem turned out to be react-hot-loader running in our local environment.

Comment: this reads more like a comment than an answer. Once you have sufficient reputation on this site you will be allowed to comment everywhere.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if you are pushing to history onclick on some dom element which also has an anchor tag.
For eg:

```
handleClick = () => {
    this.props.history.push('/url');
}

render(){
    return(
        <div onClick={() => { this.handleClick(); }}>
            <a href="">Go</a>
        </div>
    );
}
```

The above code will cause refreshing of the browser.